# Autogenerate django query with Q

Tags: python, django, reduce, django-q

for generate some query i use this code:

```
query_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', ...]
query_array = [Q(text__icontains=w) for w in query_words]
try:
  query = query_array.pop()
  for q in query_array:
    query |= q #or query &= q
  result = SomeModel.objects.filter(query)
except:
  result = SomeModel.objects.none()
```

I'm sure there's a way to write this more compact. How?
I've tried to use reduce function:

```
...
query = reduce(lambda res, q: res |= q, query_array, query_array.pop())
...
```

But I got a syntax error.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try,

```
from operator import or_
query_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', ...]
query_array = [Q(text__icontains=w) for w in query_words]
reduce(or_, query_array)
```

Comment: where the or_ coming from like method. can you give some references.